# Minimum requirements to get visa and work permit in Canada

Tags: visa, canada, job-hunting

I am an Indian. Working as a Software Engineer(Java Developer). I wish to work in Canada. I haven't got any job opportunity in this country. If i supposed to get job in Canada. How can I get visa and is there any restrictions for me like, bank deposit, assets, English Fluency exams etc. How to find out these basic things?

Comment: Please read the government sites about getting a work visa. It won't take you any longer than reading whatever answer we provide.

Answer (score 7):

Starting in 2015 (in a week from this post's original date), the Government of Canada will start a new process for candidates to immigration in Canada (the main way to be allowed to work in Canada), called Express Entry.

There is an [overview of the new system with the main steps and the main information that is necessary for this process](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/index.asp). In short, there will be a pool of candidates for permanent residence (and possibility to work), ranked by some score, depending on their skills, job offer and situation. Sometimes, the Government of Canada will pick some candidates off the pool and invite them to apply for permanent residence. Once you're picked, I imagine this is mostly a matter of paperwork.

This is not a problem that you do not have a job offer yet, however it appears to matter in the ranking score and the process includes pushing you to consult job banks and job boards to obtain a job offer.

Canada has many programs for immigrants (that you can apply through Express Entry), including for skilled people like you. There is [a page to determine your eligibility and consult these programs](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/eligibility.asp). I let you read these. There are in particular the [Federal Skilled workers program](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/apply-who.asp), and the [Quebec-selected skilled workers program](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/quebec/apply-who.asp), even though I suppose the latter has some minimal requirement about speaking French.